# Lua/Luabind: Objects constructed by objects remain allocated

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I have a simple `Lua` script

```
function TestFunction(Id)
    local Factory = TestParent();
    local ChildDirect = TestChild("DirectCall");
    local ChildFactory1 = Factory:CreateChild("Factory1");
    local ChildFactory2 = Factory:CreateChild("Factory2");

    result = Ret()
    return result
end
```

that uses two C++ exposed objects (trough [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html))

```
void TestParent::RegisterToLua(lua_State* lua)
{
  // Export our class with LuaBind
  luabind::module(lua) 
    [
        luabind::class_<TestParent>("TestParent")
            .def(luabind::constructor<>())
            .def("CreateChild", &TestParent::CreateChild)
    ];
}

void TestChild::RegisterToLua(lua_State* lua)
{
  // Export our class with LuaBind
  luabind::module(lua) 
    [
        luabind::class_<TestChild>("TestChild")
            .def(luabind::constructor<std::string>())
            .def("GetValue", &TestChild::GetValue)
    ];
}
```

I call the function

```
luabind::object obj = luabind::call_function< luabind::object >(LuaState, "TestFunction", IdParam);

if ( obj.is_valid() )
{
        ....
}

lua_gc(LuaState, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);
```

During `lua_gc` call only `Factory` and `ChildDirect` objects are destroyed. `ChildFactory1` and `ChildFactory2` remains allocated. The lua stack remains balanced (has same value - 5 - some tables ) after the `luabind::call_function`.

What is the problem ? The objects created by Factory remain somehow referenced ? By who ?

CreateChild body is

```
TestChild* TestParent::CreateChild(std::string strname)
{
    return new TestChild(strname);
}
```

The ownership of the new constructed object should be taken by `lua` object and destroyed if ChildFactory1 or ChildFactory2 is `nil`-ed or out of scope.

Comment: Just a hunch, but try calling lua_gc twice in a row. Lua uses an incremental garbage collector which runs over a period of time, so it may be possible that only one call doesn't do a complete collection+finalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[adopt](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#adopt): Used to transfer ownership across language boundaries.

```
module(L)
[
    def("create", &create, adopt(result))
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return a smart pointer (i.e. a `boost::shared_ptr`) from your factory.

see: LuaBind [Documentation # smart pointer](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#smart-pointers)

and a discussion in the [LuaBridge docu](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html#s3.4)